# Trouble shoot Pdm Add-In : Class ID not found in registry

Tags: c#, add-in, solidworks

Trying to create a Solidworks PDM Add-In to retrieve information from our Epicor ERP system and add it to vars in a data card in PDM.

To retrieve the information from our Epicor erp system. I have added the necessary .dll references and set copy local to true.

It will work fine when loaded as a Debug Add-In, but it gives this error when loading as a live Add-In.
[Pdm error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaarB.png)
"Error creating the add-in COM object from the DLL "Epicor.Mfg.BO.SysConfig.dll"
Cause: The add-in registration succeded but the add-in's class ID could not be found in the registry."

If every user has the Epicor software on their machine. Could it potentially cause issues to register the .dll using regasm.exe? Would it have to be done on everyone's machine who could use the add-in?

Any suggestions ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked this post: https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/77758

Comment: Yes, as near as I can tell it does not apply. Thanks.

Comment: Did you register Release assembly as 64bit? I suppose you are using 64 bit SolidWorks.

Comment: We are using 64 bit Sw., the solution platform is "Any CPU", with prefer 32 bit unchecked. Thanks.

Comment: You need to run 64 bit RegAsm.exe in order to register assembly. Please refer this command as example. c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe "file.dll" /tlb /codebase /verbose

Comment: A little late but you should consider talking to Epicor via the REST API as it will mean you don't need any Epicor dlls which will remove this issue and also mean you don't have to re-compile your addin each time Epicor is upgraded.

Also check out https://www.epiusers.help/ for a good forum of Epicor experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the library which is not compatible with SOLIDWORKS PDM (I'm not sure exactly the reasons but some of the libraries are causing conflict on registration). For example you might be using the System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll in your project. Please see 
[Failed to add SOLIDWORKS PDM Add-in - Class ID could not be found in the registry](https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-pdm-api/troubleshooting/addins/class-id-not-found-registry/) article for more information

Answer (score 1):

have you set your assembly to be COMVisible?

in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

Comment: What .NET framework are you targeting? Do not use [assembly: ComVisible(true)] as PDM would try to instantiate all classes in your dll to see if it is an add-in and may encounter wrong one, rather put [ComVisible] attribute on your add-in class only.

I would also recommend to explicitly assign the Guid attribute to your class. Check this article: https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-pdm-api/getting-started/add-ins/create/

Comment: Initially , the assembly ComVisible attribute was set as "false". After Andrews reply I changed it to "true", to test the result. Which produced the same error result.

Comment: Do you have [Guid("some guid")] and [ComVisible(true)] before class name?

Comment: What is your target .NET Framework version? If it is above 4.0 set the 'Embed Interop Types' option to False for EdmLib.
Are you using the interop (from .NET tab) or tlb from COM tab? You should be using the one from .NET tab.